# Matlab-Python translation error

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

**Matlab Code:**

```
AP(queryIdx) = diff([0;recall]')*prec
```

**My python code:**

```
AP[queryIdx] = np.dot(np.diff(np.concatenate(([[0]], recall), axis=0).transpose()),prec)
```

**Variables:**(Checked and am quite sure they are equivalent in python and in Matlab)

```
Recall: 1000x1 np array*
prec: 1000x1 np array
```

* prints out as [[.],.....,[.]]

**Results:**
    Matlab: .1011
    Python:  0.05263158

Only cause I can think of outside of the code is that python uses more
precision, but I doubt that would make such a large difference)

*Edit There was a problem with my prec variable. The above code worked

Comment: It might have to do with how matlab and python handle boundary conditions in the `diff` operator.

Comment: In Matlab, ' is the conjugate transpose.

Comment: @imaluengo - MATLAB and `numpy` compute `diff` the same way for 1D arrays.

Comment: @seb Using `.conj().transpose()` didn't work either :(

Comment: Then provide a minimal example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code looks a bit messy.  Try replacing it with this:

```
AP[queryIdx] = np.dot(np.diff(np.hstack([0, recall.ravel()])), prec.ravel())
```

In your post, you mentioned that you have a 1000 x 1 array for both `recall` and `prec`.  This to me is interpreted as a 2D array with a singleton dimension: the second dimension.  As such, you'd need to convert this back to a 1D array using `ravel`.

Now, `np.hstack` horizontally stacks 1D arrays together and so this will append a 0 at the front, then apply the `diff` operator, and the perform the dot product with `prec`.

One common gotcha that MATLAB coders have with `numpy` is the representation of 1D arrays in `numpy`.  There is no such thing as the transpose of a 1D array.  All `numpy` 1D arrays are row vectors.  If you explicitly want to make the 1D array a column vector, you need to include an additional dimension and make the second dimension 1, then transpose it.  Something like this:

```
r = v[:][None].T
```

---

In any case, let's verify the results:

## MATLAB

```
>> recall = (1:1000).';
>> prec = (1000:-1:1).';
>> diff([0; recall].')*prec

ans =

      500500
```

## Python (IPython)

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: recall = np.arange(1,1001)

In [3]: prec = np.arange(1000,0,-1)

In [4]: np.dot(np.diff(np.hstack([0, recall.ravel()])), prec.ravel())
Out[4]: 500500
```

Comment: I could only use hstack by reshaping recall: `np.hstack( [0, recall.reshape((10000,))] )`. That ,possibly because of what you said, gave me the same wrong answer.

Comment: @user5046480 - You didn't tell me that `recall` is a 2D array with a singleton dimension.  Either way, I'm not sure what else is wrong. Sorry.  If you want me to help further, please **give us the data you used to reconstruct your error**.

Comment: @user5046480 - Interesting.  You accepted my answer.  Thanks!  What happened?  How did you end up fixing it?